# Excel Identify unique values in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, uniqueidentifier, distinct-values

I am trying to identify unique values in a range by placing a 1 or 0 next to value if it has been repeated or not.

```
ex:
      A          B
5368907942322    1
5368907942322    0
5368907942322    0
5368907942323    1
5368907942323    0
5368907942323    0
5368907942324    1 
5368907942325    1
```

Will be using 1 or 0 as criteria for another formula

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

In `B1` your formula would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,1,0)
```

However, if you want to check for uniqueness this is what you need:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1,1,0)
```

Comment: this formula only recognizes values if they have no been repeated.  I need to recognize values even if they are later repeated in data.

Comment: This formula marks the first occurrence of value, same as you showed in your example. Otherwise, see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question right, a simple if statement should work:

```
=If(A2=A1,0,1)
```

[image]

Just enter the formula and drag it down.

Comment: Your example works, but only with ordered/sorted data.

Comment: Admittedly; however, the list provided was ordered so I made an assumption based on that to provide the most elegant (simple) answer.  The other answer is more robust. :)